# Why can't I put my laptop to suspend/sleep mode?

Tags: debian, thinkpad

Every so often on my Debian squeeze, when I hold down the shutdown button I don't get the options to suspend, etc.

Would anyone have a clue as to why this occurs? Seems like a kernel bug.

```
meder@dunross:~$ cat /etc/debian_version 
squeeze/sid
meder@dunross:~$ uname -r
2.6.32-5-686
```

My laptop is a Thinkpad T-61, by the way.

If I start my computer up 10 times, 5 of those times I'll be able to suspend it

Comment: This may be useful:  http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Installing_Debian_Lenny_on_a_ThinkPad_T60#Configuring_ACPI

Comment: Did this ever work on Debian on that laptop?

Comment: @Tshepang - yes, it usually works. It inconsistently works.

Comment: Your question title makes it look like you can't put laptop to suspend *at all*. You wanna change it?

Comment: @Tshepang - If I start my computer up 10 times, 5 of those times I'll be able to suspend it.

Comment: That's the info that actually should be on the post itself. People must figure out exactly what you want without having to read a single comment.

Answer (score 1):

There are a host of different packages and methods to manage power on Linux systems. The Debian Wiki has an [extensive writeup](http://wiki.debian.org/Suspend) on this subject.

If you have all the required bits already installed, I suggest you try running s2ram/s2disk manually from a root shell to see if that works consistently.